# Github actions how to escape characters in commit message

Tags: escaping, github-actions

Hello I'm sending the commit message to a webhook triggerin a notification with curl during my GitHub action.

```bash
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{ "commit":"${{github.event.head_commit.message}}",...}'
```

It isn't working with commit's messages including `"`, example if the commit's message is: `feat(#7): replace "FAQ" by "Help Center"`

The GitHub Action will try to execute curl this way:

```bash
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{ "commit":"feat(#7): replace "FAQ" by "Help Center"",...}'
```

Resulting in errors...

I tried to escape the double quotes with this code:

```yaml
- run: echo "GITHUB_COMMIT=$(echo ${{github.event.head_commit.message}} | sed 's/"/\\"/g')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

But again the Github Action is replacing the value "literally" in my deploy.yml during execution:

```
Run echo "GITHUB_COMMIT=$(echo feat(#7): replace "FAQ" by "Help Center" | sed 's/"/\\"/g')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
/home/runner/work/_temp/1e27e232-c415-42e0-8ab8-88bb836a0c08.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Is there any way to perform operations on the GitHub action context properties? (Like a replace here) ?

Comment: [toJSON](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) `-d '{ "commit": ${{ toJSON(github.event.head_commit.message)}}, ...}'`